# File not being read till the end

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am new to Android Development and Java. Please bear with me.

So, I am making an application which opens a random webpage from a list of webpage
The code reads a text file present in the assets folder which contains all the links, and makes a list of the links and then selects one at random.

So the problem is that I have put in log messages, to check if the program is reading and populating the array till the last line of the text.

The log messages show the size of the list as 1301. Whereas my text file contains 2601 links.
I can't to seem to understand where am I going wrong.

Here is the java code snippet,

```
    int sd=0;
    List<String> links=new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream assetIn = assetManager.open("android");
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(assetIn));
        while (r.readLine() != null) {
            links.add(r.readLine());
            sd++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        Random r=new Random();
        //String len= Integer.toString(links.size());

        String len= Integer.toString(sd);
        Log.i("total loop",len);
        String randomLink=links.get(r.nextInt(links.size()));
        Log.i("link select :",randomLink);
        webView.loadUrl(randomLink);
```

Comment: Please keep typing: you've not asked the question yet.

Comment: Maybe he accidentally hit post give him a sec before down voting to hell :)

Comment: Did you press enter too quickly?

Comment: Come on guys, don't up-vote (or down-vote) this yet either. Let's wait ...

Comment: Yep, come on guys, let's upvote it all ))

Comment: Yes, I accidentally hit the post button. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read line on loop twicely, here:

1) `while (r.readLine() != null) {`
2) `links.add(r.readLine());`

So it should be:

```
    String line = "";
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        links.add(line);
        sd++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `readLine()` twice, thus reading 2 lines instead of 1 on each iteration:

```
while (r.readLine() != null) { // reads a line
    links.add(r.readLine()); // reads another line
    sd++; // increments by 1 every *2* lines read
}
```

You probably wanted to use:

```
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
   links.add(line);
   sd++;
}
```